# How to perform a conditional groupby with polars and python

Tags: python, group-by, python-polars, rust-polars

I'd like to perform a groupby on the polars dataframe below:

```
import polars as pl 
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar'], 
    'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'two', 'two'], 
    'C' : [1, 5, 5, 2, 5, 7], 
    'D' : [2.0, 5., 8., 1., 2., 9.]
    })
```

I tried to perform the following operation:

```
df[[‘A’,‘C’]].groupby(‘A’).agg( pl.col(‘C’).apply(lambda x: x >= x.mean()).alias(‘C’) )
```

However, the result is not what I need, which would be, for each group “A” to return the values of C greater than or equal to the mean within each group A.

Answer (score 1):

- You can do a `filter` within an aggregation.
- You don't need to "pre-select" A/C like above, `agg` will automatically just select whatever you aggregate after grouping by `A`.

```py
df.group_by('A').agg(pl.col('C').filter(pl.col('C') >= pl.col('C').mean()))
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬───────────┐
│ A   ┆ C         │
│ --- ┆ ---       │
│ str ┆ list[i64] │
╞═════╪═══════════╡
│ foo ┆ [5, 5]    │
│ bar ┆ [5, 7]    │
└─────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: how do you return values in int64 format instead of a matching list?

Comment: Why do you not want a list column? Since there could be different amounts of values per list in the column, there's no reliable way to unnest it.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [window function](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/expressions/window/). The difference between a window function and a typical group_by/agg is that with a window function, it returns the same number of rows as you started with. That means you can use them in any context.

For example you could do:

```
df.with_columns(Cgroupmean=pl.col('C').mean().over('A'))
shape: (6, 5)
┌─────┬───────┬─────┬─────┬────────────┐
│ A   ┆ B     ┆ C   ┆ D   ┆ Cgroupmean │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---        │
│ str ┆ str   ┆ i64 ┆ f64 ┆ f64        │
╞═════╪═══════╪═════╪═════╪════════════╡
│ foo ┆ one   ┆ 1   ┆ 2.0 ┆ 3.666667   │
│ bar ┆ one   ┆ 5   ┆ 5.0 ┆ 4.666667   │
│ foo ┆ two   ┆ 5   ┆ 8.0 ┆ 3.666667   │
│ bar ┆ three ┆ 2   ┆ 1.0 ┆ 4.666667   │
│ foo ┆ two   ┆ 5   ┆ 2.0 ┆ 3.666667   │
│ bar ┆ two   ┆ 7   ┆ 9.0 ┆ 4.666667   │
└─────┴───────┴─────┴─────┴────────────┘
```

Since what you want to do is filter for when the `C` is bigger than the group mean you can just put `pl.col('C').mean().over('A'))` in your filter instead of adding it to your df like this:

```
df.filter(pl.col("C")>=pl.col('C').mean().over('A'))
shape: (4, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ D   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ str ┆ i64 ┆ f64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ bar ┆ one ┆ 5   ┆ 5.0 │
│ foo ┆ two ┆ 5   ┆ 8.0 │
│ foo ┆ two ┆ 5   ┆ 2.0 │
│ bar ┆ two ┆ 7   ┆ 9.0 │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```